# Recorrer un json para armar un select múltiple

Tags: php, html5

Tengo un usuario que en un select múltiple selecciona varias opciones. Obtengo los `values` seleccionados y los grabo en la base de datos como un `json`. Antes de almacenar los datos ejecuto un `json_encode`. Lo que guardo en la base de datos, tiene este formato:

```
["1","2","4"]
```

Siendo cada número el `"value"` que fue seleccionado. Ahora bien, cuando quiero mostrar nuevamente los datos que eligió el usuario en el select multiple, pensaba que podría recorrer el `json` almacenado y marcar ese `value` como "selected"

```
foreach($valorDevuelto as $obj){
    $valor = $obj->valor;
    echo $valor;
}
```

el problema que al recorrerlo, no me devuelve los valores como para poder analizarlos.

En cuanto cómo activarlos podría hacer algo asi:

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Tipo de Perfil:</label>
  <select id="select" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="claseUsuario[]">
    foreach($valorDevuelto as $obj){
    $valor = $obj->valor;

    if($valor == 1) { ?>
      <option value="1" selected>Opcion 1</option>
    } else{
      <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
    }

    etc...

    }
    <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
    <option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
   </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo muchachos, lo resolvi solito... jejejejeje les paso la solución por si le sirve a alguien:

```
$array = json_decode ($valorDevuelto, true);
?>

<div class="field">
<label>Tipo de Perfil:</label>
<select id="select" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="claseUsuario[]">

  <?php
  foreach ($array as $key=> $values) {
      if($values == "1") { ?>
        <option value="1" selected>Opcion 1</option>
      <?php } else{ ?>
        <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
      <?php }

      if($values == "2") { ?>
        <option value="2" selected>Opcion 2</option>
      <?php } else{ ?>
        <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
      <?php }

      if($values == "3") { ?>
        <option value="3" selected>Opcion 3</option>
      <?php } else{ ?>
        <option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
      <?php }

      if($values == "4") { ?>
        <option value="4" selected>Opcion 4</option>
      <?php } else{ ?>
        <option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
      <?php }
} ?>

  </select>
  <div class="ui visible blue mini message">
    <p>No seleccione nada si es un usuario común</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

esto hace que te toma el valor del json almacenado y lo parsea para activar o no los distintos values del select multiple... obviamente esto es aplicable para cualquier select sea múltiple o no...